# Can I change DNS header flags that is not supposed to be changed in response?

Tags: dns, udp

I am working on a program that creates dummy DNS response from a valid query. Suppose the recursion desired flag is 1 in the query and I change it to 0. Will the response message work in the client machine after changing the RD value which was not supposed to be changed in the response query.

Comment: What is the purpose? Testing a DNS client (and hence sending him edge cases is a good way to test how it behaves) or just sending valid replies as any real world nameserver will do (in which case trying to go into edge cases is not really useful)? Also at this stage, without any more code, your question is kind of offtopic here.

Comment: I want to create a fake dns response with my program generated flag field. I want to know if the client can recognize the bit I have changed if the flag field that does not change in response ( like recursion desired flag does not change in response message)

Comment: RD is defined as "Recursion Desired - this bit may be set in a query and
                is copied into the response." It will probably get ignored by the client (as it is of no use in a response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer after implementing the code. and answer is 
yes header flags can be altered or changed to anything. as long as the flag that indicate that the packet is a response everything will be fine. sender will not check if the flags that the sender sent is changed or not.